# switch inside another switch actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have this lines of code that are very long and i want to know if this codes can be converted from this

```
if(BtnInteracted == "New"){
        if(sample_1.SaveSlotNumber == "1"){
            if(){

            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if(sample_1.SaveSlotNumber == "2"){
            if(){

            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if(sample_1.SaveSlotNumber == "3"){
            if(){

            }
            else{

            }
        }
    }


    else if (BtnInteracted == "Con"){
        if(sample_1.SaveSlotNumber == "1"){
            if(){

            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if(sample_1.SaveSlotNumber == "2"){
            if(){

            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if(sample_1.SaveSlotNumber == "3"){
            if(){

            }
            else{

            }
        }
    }
```

to this.

```
switch(BtnInteracted){
    case "New": switch (sample_1.SaveSlotNumber){
                    case "1": //if() else() statement;
                    case "2": //if() else() statement;
                    case "3": //if() else() statement;
                } break;

    case "Con": switch (sample_1.SaveSlotNumber){
                    case "1": //if() else() statement;
                    case "2": //if() else() statement;
                    case "3": //if() else() statement;
                } break;
}
```

is it even possible to make this code or my original is my only option?
thanks for any reply!

Comment: It will work fine - just put in break; statements in the second set of switches.  Also, having a default: might not be bad idea as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful with the `break` statements, but it will work. You can nest switches, but personally I dont't think inner switches are more readable; I prefer pass stuff to functions:

```
switch(BtnInteracted)
{
    case "New": 
    {
       startFrom(sample_1.SaveSlotNumber);
       break;
    }
    case "Con": 
    {
       continueFrom(sample_1.SaveSlotNumber);
       break;
    }
}
```

And then use a new switch in the button

```
function startFrom(index:int):void
{
  trace("start from ", index);
  switch(index)
  {
    case 1: 
    {
       // do something
       break;
    }
    case 2: 
    {
       // do something
       break;
    }
  }
}

function continueFrom(index:int):void
{
  trace("continue from", index);
  switch(index)
  {
    case 1: 
    {
       // do something
       break;
    }
    case 2: 
    {
       // do something
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

In lots of cases you'll need the function multiple times with other input so you dont have you repeat yourself and it keeps clear what happens with a specific *case*.